# Best practice for browser specific content

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a project where I need to show specific content & include a file for a specific set of browsers.

I'm starting off with IE.

Since IE10 conditional comments aren't a thing anymore I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is for including specific content and a specific javascript file with some general fixes for things like css variables aswell.

So far I got something for just "exclusive" JS code but, I only want the file to be included based on what browser is being used.

```
 if (/Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent) || /rv:11.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
   document.write('<script src="./js/app-legacy-browsers.js"></script>');           
 }
```

Other than that I need to show the active browser icon on the site with some pre-set content.

I'd like to accomplish the same result as if 
`<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` still existed.

Main reason of not wanting to use the if statement is not wanting to affect pagespeed on first load.

Comment: It always helps to explain the reasoning behind wanting to do this sort of thing. The correct answer will likely be different according to why you're doing what you're doing and also which specific browsers you're targeting.

Comment: The main reason would be not effecting pagespeed or atleast the least possible. I'm afraid it would have some impact with the JS way.

Comment: Best practice is to not do browser (version) sniffing and to just test for support of features individually. And depending on if a feature is supported or not you can either implement version A (with feature) or use another approach (without feature)

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by 'affecting pagespeed'? MS Edge isn't a particularly slow browser generally, so unless you have a specific problem with it, I don't know why you'd be targeting it because you're worried about page speed. Since you said 'pagespeed' without a space, I wonder if you mean Google's pagespeed ranking? If that's what your thinking about, then you don't need to worry about individual browsers, because Google doesn't take different browsers into account when looking at the pagespeed ranking.

Comment: @Spudley This was the kind of clarification I was looking for. I thought this way it would affect "page speed" & "Google Pagespeed" but, apparently not. Thank you for clearing this out.

Comment: You should definitely go with the JS approach which you had already shown in your original post will help to identify the specific version of browser and you can than load your files.